# onLocationChanged called only the first time i open the application, but not anymore if app becomes inactive and active again

Tags: android, gps

i'm trying to build a GPS app with Android Studio. It's working okay on the first run but whenever i close the app and open it again or go to desktop and back into it, as i have figured until now, my LocationListener doesn't get called anymore.

Practically what happens is that it doesn't display my location as intended the second time. No error no anything.

Here's my code, thanks in advance if you can help. I've been searching a lot :(

```
    package com.madnzz.googlemapsstuff;

    import android.*;
    import android.Manifest;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
    import android.graphics.Camera;
    import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
    import android.location.Location;
    import android.location.LocationListener;
    import android.location.LocationManager;
    import android.os.Build;
    import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
    import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.ImageButton;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
    import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
    import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.GroundOverlay;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.GroundOverlayOptions;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

    import java.sql.Time;
    import java.util.Random;


    import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.AndroidAppUri;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptor;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;

    import static com.madnzz.googlemapsstuff.R.id.activity_chooser_view_content;
    import static com.madnzz.googlemapsstuff.R.id.repositionButton;


    /*
    TODO: Replace retard user icon with improved one
            *IMPLEMENT the way the user is facing.  http://android-coding.blogspot.ro/2012/03/create-our-android-compass.html
            *
    TODO: implement GPS routes https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CCZPUeY94MU      or        http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/drawing-driving-route-directions-between-two-locations-using-google-directions-in-google-map-android-api-v2/
            *REPLACE consumed path with cookie crumb graphic

    TODO: save path and able to share with others.

         TODO later: Battery efficiency https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html

    */

    public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

            private GoogleMap mMap;
            LocationManager locationManager;
            LocationListener locationListener;
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        @Override
        public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

            if (requestCode == 1) {

                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    startListening();

                }

            }

        }


        public void startListening() {

            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

            }

        }

        Random random=new Random();
        GroundOverlayOptions[] c00kieCrumb=new GroundOverlayOptions[200];
        int i=0;
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        public void addCrumb(LatLng userLocation){
            int randomCrumbBearing=random.nextInt(36)*10;

            c00kieCrumb[i] = new GroundOverlayOptions()
                    .image(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.frateeeee))
                    .position(userLocation, 3,3).bearing(randomCrumbBearing);
            c00kieCrumb[i].isVisible();
            i++;
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                mMap.addGroundOverlay(c00kieCrumb[j]);
            }
        }//adds new cookie crumb to user location

        public void putCrumbConditions(LatLng userLocation){

            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                mMap.addGroundOverlay(c00kieCrumb[j]);
            }
            if (i == 0) {
                addCrumb(userLocation);

            } else {
                if (Math.abs((c00kieCrumb[i - 1].getLocation().latitude - userLocation.latitude)) > 0.00003
                        || Math.abs(c00kieCrumb[i - 1].getLocation().longitude - userLocation.longitude) > 0.00003) {
                    addCrumb(userLocation);
                }
            }
        }//adds a new cookie crumb to the user location 4
                                                            // IF THE USER IS 0.00003 UNITS AWAY FROM LAST CRUMB PLACED


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            Log.i("ZiciCinci created shit", "Am ajuns aici");

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
            // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
            SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onDestroy(Bundle savedInstanceState){
            super.onDestroy();
        }

        LatLng [] locationCalibrator,savedUserLocation;
        LatLng userLocation,previousUserLocation;
        Boolean gpsCalibrationInProgress,tooClose,firstIteration,mapCenteredOnUserPosition,cameraFollowUserPosition;
        int locationIteration=0,savedUserLocationPos;
        ImageButton repositionButton;



        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

            Log.i("ZiciPatru map is ready","Am ajuns aici");


            mMap = googleMap;
            c00kieCrumb[0] = new GroundOverlayOptions();
            locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            locationCalibrator = new LatLng[100];
            gpsCalibrationInProgress = true;
            locationIteration = 0;
            i = 0;
            savedUserLocation = new LatLng[3];
            savedUserLocationPos = 0;
            tooClose = true;
            firstIteration = true;
            mapCenteredOnUserPosition = true;
            cameraFollowUserPosition = true;
            previousUserLocation = new LatLng(0, 0);


            locationListener = new LocationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                    Log.i("Zici3 gps calibration","Am ajuns aici");

                    userLocation = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

                        if (!gpsCalibrationInProgress) {

                            if (Math.abs(previousUserLocation.latitude - userLocation.latitude) > 0.000003 ||
                                    Math.abs(previousUserLocation.latitude - userLocation.longitude) > 0.000003) {
                                mMap.clear();
                                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(userLocation).title("Your Location").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.edytardin64x64)).rotation(0));
                                if (firstIteration) {
                                    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(userLocation, 15));
                                    firstIteration = false;
                                }

                                LatLng userDestination = new LatLng(44.4187432, 26.1556372);

                                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(userDestination).title("COOOOKIESTUFF").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.c00ki3_marker_128x128)));

                                putCrumbConditions(userLocation);
                            }
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Calibrating gps, please stand still", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            locationCalibrator[locationIteration] = userLocation;
                            locationIteration++;
                            if (locationIteration >= 2) {
                                if (Math.abs(locationCalibrator[locationIteration - 1].latitude - userLocation.latitude) < 0.0001
                                        && Math.abs(locationCalibrator[locationIteration - 1].longitude - userLocation.longitude) < 0.0001
                                        && Math.abs(locationCalibrator[locationIteration - 2].latitude - userLocation.latitude) < 0.0001
                                        && Math.abs(locationCalibrator[locationIteration - 2].latitude - userLocation.latitude) < 0.0001) {
                                    gpsCalibrationInProgress = false;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    previousUserLocation = userLocation;

                    repositionButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.repositionButton);


                    repositionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Log.i("rarara","q");
                            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(userLocation, 15));
                            repositionButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.location_centered);
                            mapCenteredOnUserPosition = true;
                            cameraFollowUserPosition = true;
                        }
                    });

                    if (mapCenteredOnUserPosition) {
                        mMap.setOnCameraMoveStartedListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveStartedListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCameraMoveStarted(int reason) {
                                if (reason == GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveStartedListener.REASON_GESTURE) {
                                    repositionButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.location_not_centered);
                                    mapCenteredOnUserPosition = false;
                                    cameraFollowUserPosition = false;
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }

                    if (cameraFollowUserPosition) {
                        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(userLocation, 15));
                        repositionButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.location_centered);
                    }
                LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(GoogleApiClient,this)
                }

                @Override
                public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please activate your location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

                }

            };


            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23) {
                startListening();
            } else {

                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);

                } else {

                    Location lastKnownLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                    if (lastKnownLocation != null) {
                        LatLng userLocation = new LatLng(lastKnownLocation.getLatitude(), lastKnownLocation.getLongitude());

                        if (!tooClose) {
                            mMap.clear();
                            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(userLocation).title("Your Location").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.edytardin64x64)));
                        }
                        tooClose = false;
                    } else {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

My android manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.madnzz.googlemapsstuff">

    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
         location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"


        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <!--
             android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
             -->
        <!--
             The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
             (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
             Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
             You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
             sign the APK for publishing.
             You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And layout file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MapsActivity" >

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.madnzz.googlemapsstuff.MapsActivity"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/repositionButton"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"/>
        <!--android:onClick="repositionMap"-->
        android:background="@drawable/location_not_centered" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Location lastKnownLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

if (lastKnownLocation != null) {
    LatLng userLocation = new LatLng(lastKnownLocation.getLatitude(), 
    lastKnownLocation.getLongitude());

    if (!tooClose) {
        mMap.clear();
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(userLocation).title("Your Location").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.edytardin64x64)));
    }

    tooClose = false;
} else {
  locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
        LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
}
```

The problematic part of the your code(and also scenario),

You did make location request if `lastKnownLocation`is null. After receiving new location one time(onLocationChanged), `getLastKnownLocation`will not return null, and location request will not be called for later starts(except boot)

As a result, onLocationChanged called only one time.

---

`getLastKnownLocation` will give you the latest location obtained from given provider.It's possible to get null. You just used `GPS_PROVIDER` but could also try `NETWORK_PROVIDER` too

```
mGpsLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
mNetworkLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
```

With this you can increase chance of getting a location. If both of them null then make location request provider(s) (sorry there is no magic, you must, like others do)

Comment: Riiiiiight. I didn't even think about that part of the code. What do you suggest i do to make my application try again and again to get the last known location ? I added that IF statement because if i didn't, the app would crash on my mobile device saying something along the lines that it can't be null.

Comment: Please ? I'm stuck :(